# How to make Listview of unique buttons in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, button, audio

I'm developing an app that creates a list of audio recordings. For every recording I want the app to generate different interface for recording and playing the audio, some sort of form that keeps the name and unique id of the recording. It looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf9lp.png)

Unfortunately when i press the play button on one of those recordings, every single play button for all recordings toggles from Icons.play to Icons.stop. I only want the desired button to change icon, I tried using Keys and GlobalKeys but with no success.

code for audioForm looks like this

```
  _audioForm(double screenWidth, double screenHeight, recordi) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: screenHeight / 9,
              width: screenWidth * (2 / 10),
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Key'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: screenHeight / 9,
              width: screenWidth * (5 / 10),
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Name'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: screenWidth * 1.5 / 10,
              child: Center(
                child: InkWell(
                  key: Key("record"),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet(
                        (BuildContext context) => _recordBottomSheet(
                            screenWidth, screenHeight, recordingList[recordi]));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: screenWidth * 1.5 / 10,
              child: Center(
                child: InkWell(
                  child: _isPlaying
                      ? Icon(
                          Icons.stop,
                          size: 35,
                        )
                      : Icon(
                          Icons.play_arrow,
                          size: 35,
                        ),
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_isPlaying == true)
                      _isPlaying = false;
                    else
                      _isPlaying = true;
                    setState(() {
                    });
                    // }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

I excluded code regarding sound operations, since it's unimportant for this case, I only left the bool that toggles button. I would really appreciate some advice on how to make every button unique to a recording.

And this is Listview, in which audio forms are stored

```
child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: recordingList.length + 1,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index < recordingList.length) {
                  return _audioForm(screenWidth, screenHeight, index);
                } else {
                  return _addButton();
                }
              }),
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers checkout this package might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All buttons in your code are using the same bool variable...
So if you call setState() the entire widget-tree will be rebuild an all buttons will update their appearence to the changed bool value.
Try to create a new StatefulWidget where every button will have its own specific bool value.

Or use a map with bool values, like this

```
Map<int,bool> isPlaying = {
//example values
0: true,
1: false,
};
```

your onTap-method should then look like this:

```
onTap: () {
    isPlaying.update(index, (value) => !value, ifAbsent: ()=> true);
   setState(() {});
    },
```

your icon widget should look like this:

```
child: 
      Icon(
        (_isPlaying[index] ?? false) ? Icons.stop : Icons.play_arrow,
        size: 35,
       ),
```